# Heroku meteor/meteorite deployment

Tags: heroku, meteor, meteorite

I have a meteor project created with meteorite under version control and I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku using the heroku buildpack [oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite) but I this error:

```
!     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

Is it a problem with the build package or I need extra configuration in my app?, It's the first time I deploy an App to heroku so I'm not very familiarized with it.

Comment: Can you try using the steps described on this [article](http://chrislunsford.com/up-and-running-with-meteor-and-heroku.html)

Comment: Thanks, that article helped me find my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question I'm very new to Heroku and this time I made a silly mistake.
In the buildpackage documentation it says you just need to use `heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git` command and then `git push`. What I did't realized was that the command creates a new app in heroku and I had mine created already.

So the solution is:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git
```